# I have a Wordpress website but i have some of unknown plugins installed frequently?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am running a wordpress website and it has some of the plugins installed which i don't know, and i have never installed those plugins. The name of those plugins are

1. Wordpress Engine Module
2. Wordpress Kernel Module

And i have 3 of the Wordpress engine module installed but its deactivated, and wordpress kernel module activated but i have not installed both the plugins and not even activated but kernel module has activated automatically and engine module is installed automatically but not activated

The most important thing is I have 3 of the plugins with the same name WordPress Engine Module, So what is the problem should i deactivate and delete those plugins or keep it.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is working fine without the plugins activated, then you can delete them. You can also make a backup of your website and then try to deactivate all the unknown plugins to see if everything is working. Make sure to analyze the site performance, time it takes to load and more with and without the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Which hosting service do you use? It sounds like these plugins were pre-installed by your host.

Comment: Hostinger service

Comment: I looked in their website, and although they do claim to pre-install plugins with WordPress, they don't list which ones are bundled. I would try contacting Hostinger support and asking them about these plugins.

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me too on several websites I maintain. WordFence marked it as malware beside others I found while scanning websites. You surely should scan your websites and delete those unknown plugins.

I don't know how they appeared there at all!